# Unknown option -Dsun.java2d.opengl=true

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to speed up NetBeans on Ubuntu.

I was reading about that on http://performance.netbeans.org/howto/jvmswitches/

I get this error:

```
sh /home/umpirsky/Applications/netbeans-7.2rc1/bin/netbeans -J-Xverify:none -J-Xmx384m -Dsun.java2d.opengl=true
Unknown option -Dsun.java2d.opengl=true
```

Should I use some special version of Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name `sun.java2d...` indicates, this is (or was)an option for the Sun/Oracle JVM, and is probably not supported by Ubuntu's default OpenJDK JVM.

You would have to install the Oracle JDK/JRE to see if that option works. It may be easier to first understand how it helps speed Netbeans up and whether you really need it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like to resurrect old threads, but the OP forgot to prepend with -J the flag in the file netbeans.conf:

```
-J-Dsun.java2d.opengl=True
```

These are my configuration flags, and netbeans runs smoothly:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-server -J-Xverify:none -J-XX:+AggressiveOpts -J-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -J-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -J-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=True -J-Dawt.nativeDoubleBuffering=True -J-Dsun.java2d.opengl=True -J-Xss32m -J-Xms64m -J-Xmx256m -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=True -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=True -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=True"
```

For more info: [See this guide on the Oracle website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.